# update the state object after the event tigger using functional component react

Tags: reactjs

I' m using the useContext hook to manage the state, i have tigger the handleChange method from the other component's input slider field, this changes the state object and that state are used to filter the data

````
this is the context API hook component
handleChange is tigger by the other component input price slider
 
 
   const handleChange = (event) => {
    const target = event.target;
    const name = target.name;
    const value = target.value;
    setState(
      {
        ...state,
        [name]: value,
      },
**Part 1
      filterBooks()
    );
  };
  const filterBooks = () => {
    let { books, maxPrice, minPrice, type, category, price } = state;
    let tempBook = [...books];
    price = parseInt(price);
    // console.log(typeof price);
    // console.log(tempBook, price);
    if (type !== "all") {
      tempBook = tempBook.filter((book) => book.type === type);
    }
    tempBook = tempBook.filter((book) => book.price < price);

**Part 2 **

   *code works as expected till here*

    setState({
      ...state,
      sortedBook: tempBook,
    });
    // how to update state in this scenario;
   // as per the docs we can't update state in nested function
  };
  return (
    <ProductContext.Provider value={{ state, handleChange }}>
      {props.children}
    </ProductContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default ProviderContext;```
````

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're filtering in the setState callback, why not just update the filter in the initial setState?

Also, unless your state is deeply nested you shouldn't need to pass the full state to the setState, and if it is nested - I'd consider a redux implementation

Comment: i haven't gone through redux yet.

Comment: It's just a global state store

Answer (score 0):

I refactor the code and it worked

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
    const target = event.target;
    const name = target.name;
    const value = target.value;
    setFlag(false);

    setState({
      ...state,
      [name]: value,
      sortedBook: [],
    });
    setFlag(true);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!flag) {
      // console.log("effect called without change - by default");
    } else {
      // console.log("effect called with change ");
      const filterBooks = () => {
        let { books, maxPrice, minPrice, type, category, price } = state;
        let tempBook = [...books];

        if (type !== "all") {
          tempBook = tempBook.filter((book) => book.type === type);
        }
        tempBook = tempBook.filter((book) => book.price < parseInt(price));
        // console.log("from tempbook", tempBook);
        setState({
          ...state,
          sortedBook: tempBook,
        });
      };

      filterBooks();
    }
    // console.log(state);
  }, [state.price, flag]);
```